# How do you get SUM() to work after grouping and have bags?

Tags: apache-pig

Can someone explain why this works:

```
data = FOREACH problem_three GENERATE $0 AS playerID, $1 AS yearID, $8 AS doubles, $9 AS triples, $10 AS HR;
filtered_years = FILTER data BY (yearID=='1980' OR yearID=='1981'OR yearID=='1982'OR yearID=='1983'OR yearID=='1984'OR yearID=='1985'OR 
yearID=='1986'OR yearID=='1987'OR yearID=='1988'OR yearID=='1989');
extra_bases_total = FOREACH filtered_years GENERATE playerID, doubles+triples+HR AS yearly_total;
players_grouped = GROUP extra_bases_total BY playerID;
sums = FOREACH players_grouped GENERATE group, SUM(extra_bases_total.yearly_total) AS total;
grouped_all = GROUP sums ALL;
```

but this doesn't:

```
Batting = LOAD 'hdfs:/user/maria_dev/pigtest/Batting.csv' USING PigStorage(',');
batting_details = FOREACH Batting GENERATE $0 AS playerID, $11 AS RBI;
batting_detail = FOREACH batting_details GENERATE playerID, RBI;
batting_details_groupeddata = GROUP batting_detail BY playerID;
totals = FOREACH batting_details_groupeddata GENERATE group, SUM(batting_detail.RBI) AS total;
DUMP totals;
```

What I am trying to do is get a sum of the RBIs for each player in the second part.  I've tried filtering out the nulls and a bunch of other re-writing but nothing is working.  SUM seems like a simple function but I cannot get it to work after I make a group.

Comment: Could be some sort of type issue for values in the RBI column, are you able to cast them to (int) or something?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, at one point I did try $11 AS RBI:int.  I also tried float too but that didn't work.

Comment: So I think using :int is just telling the schema to interpret the field as an int, not actually cast it to an int. Putting (int) before the value, like (int)RBI should actually try to cast it as an int type